# what is the difference between --force-rm and --rm when running docker build command

Tags: docker

When we build docker images using `docker build` command we have two options `--force-rm=true` and `--rm=true` to remove intermediate containers. what is the difference between these two options and in what scenarios should each be used.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

docker build has:

```
--rm=true                       Remove intermediate containers after a successful build
```

That means that, in case of an unsuccessful build, those intermediate containers are *not* removed. That allows for debugging the last intermediate container, or committing it as an intermediate image.

But with `--force-rm=true`, those intermediate containers would *always* been removed even in case of an unsuccessful compilation.

Comment: What you are saying is for `docker rm some_container_id` context. My query is regarding `docker build some_app . --force-rm=true` vs `docker build some_app . --rm=true`. I do not understand the difference in capabilities of these two seemingly similar flags.

Comment: @Vikram3891 OK, I have rewritten the answer accordingly.